# How isn't the European Council included as a Privileged Applicant in Art 263 TFEU?

Tags: european-council

Nigel Foster. [*EU Law Directions* 6 ed. 2018](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/eu-law-directions-9780198816539?cc=ca&lang=en&). p. 241

> #### 9.1.2.1 Privileged
>
> Privileged applicants are named by Article 263 TFEU as the member states, the Council, and the
>   Commission, and, following the Treaty of Nice, the EP, all of which have the right to attack any act.
>   Notably, despite its elevation to a full institution by the Lisbon Treaty in Article 13 of the Treaty on
>   European Union (TEU), **the European Council is not included**. It may be, as with the EP previously,
>   that the CoJ has to step in to provide that right should the European Council seek to bring an action
>   under Article 263 TFEU, although, of course, any of the members of the European Council could
>   bring an action in their own right as a member state.
>
> #### 9.1.2.2 Limited or semi-privileged
>
> Semi-privileged applicants comprise a category first established in case law for the EP by the CoJ;
>   but, following its elevation to a full Union institution, named in Article 7 EC (now 13 TEU), the EP
>   moved out of this category. The Treaty of Amsterdam added to the semi-privileged category the
>   Court of Auditors, which has the right to challenge acts of the institutions, but only for the purpose
>   of protecting its prerogatives. The right was extended to the European Central Bank (ECB) by the
>   TEU. The term ‘protection of prerogatives’ is one that was essentially developed in case law and
>   means ‘where their interests are clearly affected’.
>
> See, for example, Case 138/79 *Maizena (Roquette Freres) v Council*, as confirmed in Cases
>   C-70/88 *EP v Council (Chernobyl)* and C-295/90 *EP v Council (Students Residence Directive)*,
>   in which the challenge by the EP to the legal base used by the Council was successful.

p. 242

> This limited right of challenge is now confirmed in Article 263 TFEU. The original locus standi reflected
>   the original much lesser and more limited law-making and participatory role of the EP, and
>   the extensions over time to the EP and now to the Court of Auditors and ECB reflect the fact that
>   the decision-making of those bodies can also have far-reaching consequences. The Lisbon Treaty has
>   added the Committee of the Regions (CoR) to the category of semi-privileged applicants, but oddly,
>   in the light of the latter change, it does not add the European Economic and Social Committee
>   (EESC) or even the **European Council**, which, as a self-standing institution, is thus excluded from any
>   privileged applicant status. The member states individually, though, still possess full privilege.
>
> All other persons are non-privileged applicants, who must satisfy certain conditions before their
>   right of access to the CoJ will be recognised.

But Article 263 TFEU  undeniably brings up and includes the European Council? p 238.

> Article 263 TFEU
>   The Court of Justice of the European Union shall review the legality of legislative acts, of acts
>   of the Council, of the Commission, of the European Central Bank, other than recommendations
>   and opinions, and of acts of the European Parliament and of the **European Council**
>   intended
>   to produce legal effects vis-à-vis third parties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portion of Article 263 that you quote doesn’t say anything about *applicants*. That’s what the following sections are about:

> It shall for this purpose have jurisdiction in actions brought by a Member State, the European Parliament, the Council or the Commission on grounds of lack of competence, infringement of an essential procedural requirement, infringement of the Treaties or of any rule of law relating to their application, or misuse of powers.
>
> The Court shall have jurisdiction under the same conditions in actions brought by the Court of Auditors, by the European Central Bank and by the Committee of the Regions for the purpose of protecting their prerogatives.
>
> Any natural or legal person may, under the conditions laid down in the first and second paragraphs, institute proceedings against an act addressed to that person or which is of direct and individual concern to them, and against a regulatory act which is of direct concern to them and does not entail implementing measures.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because its status changed after the treaty was written and it doesn't make any difference. The European Council recently became an official institution but it's still mostly a meeting between heads of state with a symbolic role. It shares its staff with the Council of the European Union and is ultimately controlled by national governments. Concretely, who would conduct such litigation? If national governments feel the need to launch an action for annulment, they may as well instruct their national civil service or the Council staff to do it.